# Using android hidden functions to manage call states

Tags: android, function, call, state, hidden

I am a beginner in android programming.
I want to use the hidden method "getState()" of "com.android.internal.telephony.call" package to manage the state of an outgoing call such as activating, ringing, answering, rejecting and disconnecting.
But there is an error in the following code on the line indicated by "******".

Any help?

My code is :

```
import com.android.internal.telephony.*;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Class myclass;
ClassLoader cloader;
Method f;
Object o;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cloader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    try {
        myclass = cloader.loadClass("com.android.internal.telephony.Call");
        // No error generated. "Call" class will be loaded.
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    try {
        f = myclass.getMethod("getState", null);
        // No error generated.Method "f" will be assigned
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    Constructor constructors[] = myclass.getDeclaredConstructors();
    // There is one constructor only
    Constructor constructor = null;
    for (int i=0; i<constructors.length;i++)
    {
        constructor = constructors[i];
        if (constructor.getGenericParameterTypes().length == 0)
            break;
        }
    constructor.setAccessible(true);
    try {
            o = constructor.newInstance(null);
    //*****an exception generated here.
    //*****Exception is "java.lang.instantationexception"
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    try {
        f = myclass.getMethod("getState", null);
        // No error
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you are passing a *null* value to the constructor. Does the Constructor accept parameters?

Comment: The "Call" class constructor does not need any parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to call private members like this. It will not work across Android versions and even across manufacturer customized ROMs of the same version.

Comment: This is particularly true for "a beginner in android programming".

Comment: You should send him a free book before he hurts someone  :)

Comment: It is not difficult to use some hidden functions for "a beginner in android programming" :) .Please see devmaze.wordpress.com. Any suggestion?